# Modular arithmetic (a*b/e)%m?

Tags: algorithm, math, modular-arithmetic, mathematical-expressions

Is there a modular expression possible for following :

```
((a*b)/e)%m
```

For ex :

```
(a*b*c)%m = ((a%m)*(b%m)*(c%m))%m
```

Comment: Is m prime? Is a * b divisible by e?

Comment: Are you asking if `%` distributes over `*`?

Comment: @user2040251 m is a prime  but a*b may or may not be exactly divisible by e

Comment: @TobiLehman No i am asking if given an expression like above if i can caculate quickly by finding out the remainders obtained from m

Comment: If a * b is not divisible by e, then no, you cannot.

Comment: @user2040251 what if it is divisible ?

Comment: @AkashRana Ah, I see

Comment: What should be the result if a*b is not divisible by e?

Comment: `c = (1/e) (mod m)`, i.e., the multiplicative inverse of `(e)` modulo `(m)` : `c.e (mod m) = 1`

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures for an algorithm for computing the multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of performing division when using modular arithmetic, you must multiply by the modular inverse. For instance, to divide by *e*, you would multiply by the modular inverse *c* where *c* × *e* ≡ 1 (mod *m*). You can calculate the modular inverse of *x* (mod *m*) by the following algorithm:

```
function inverse(x, m)
    a, b, u = 0, m, 1
    while x > 0
        q = b // x # integer division
        x, a, b, u = b % x, u, x, a - q * u
    if b == 1 return a % m
    error "must be coprime"
```

Thus, for your expression `((a*b)/e)%m` you would compute `(a * b * inverse(e,m)) % m`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean for division; for example for

```
a = 1
b = 1
e = 3
m = 7
```

what is the result you expect? 1/3 is 0 by conventional arithmetic, if it's that what you're looking for in this case then there is no shortcut in general (you can however trade the division for a multiplication and a shift if `a*b` is known to be small enough).

Another option for division `x/y` is however looking for the number that multiplied by `y` gives `x` in modular arithmetic (and `1/3` with this meaning is `5` because `5*3` is 1 when thinking modulo 7). If this is what you're looking for instead of dividing by `e` you can multiply by the modular inverse of `e` i.e. for the number that multiplied by `e` gives 1 (mod `m`).